# Estrutura lógica com problemas em C++

Tags: c++, if, lógica, else

**Será que alguém ai pode me ajudar pois a estrutura condicional do meu código fica enviando um valor duplo :

O resultado é sempre **aluno aprovado** ! **aluno em recuperação**! ou **aluno reprovado**! **aluno em recuperação** não estou conseguindo entender este comportamento será que errei na estrutura lógica ?

````
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>



using namespace std;
int main(int argc[], char * argv[])
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");
float num1, num2, num3, num4, x;
bool op;
char tecla;

    do{

                        cout << "Digite a média do primeiro bimestre do aluno : \n";
                        cin >> num1;
                        system("clear");

                        cout << "Digite a média do segundo bimestre do auluno : \n";
                        cin >> num2;
                        system("clear");

                        cout << "Digite a média do terceiro bimestre do aluno : \n";
                        cin >> num3;
                        system("clear");

                        cout << "Digite a média do quarto bimestre do aluno : \n";
                        cin >> num4;
                        system("clear");

                if((num1 > 10 || num2 > 10 || num3 > 10 || num4 > 10) || (num1 < 0  || num2 < 0 || num3 < 0 || num4 < 0)){

                        cout << "Valor invalido ! ";

                            exit(0);
                        }

                else{

                        x = ((num1 + num2 + num3 + num4) / 4);

                        cout << "A nota final do aluno é  : \n" << x "\n";

                    if(x >= 7){
                        cout << "Aluno aprovado ! \n";
                    }

                    if(x <= 5){
                        cout << "Aluno reprovado ! \n";
                    }

                    else{
                        cout << "Aluno em recuperação ! \n";
                    }


                        cout << " Deseja executar o programa novamnte ? \n";
                        
                        cout << " Caso deseje executa-lo novamente pressione (s) \n";
                        
                        cout << " Se desejar sair pressione qualquer tecla !\n";
                        
                        cin >> tecla;

                    if(tecla == 's'){
                        op = 1;
                    }

                    else{
                        system("EXIT");
                    }

        }

    }while(op != 0 );

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Entre `if(x >= 7){cout << "Aluno aprovado ! \n"; }` e `if(x <= 5){...` parece estar faltando um `else`

Answer (score -1):

A condição **if** é sempre executada, no caso de sua média seja 7, ele vai executar a primeira condição

```
if(x >= 7){
  cout << "Aluno aprovado ! \n";
          }
```

Como não tem um else abaixo ele vai para o outro if:

```
 if(x <= 5){
        cout << "Aluno reprovado ! \n";
           }
```

e como a nota é 7 a condição será falsa então ele vai executar o else que está abaixo. O correto é usar if, else if e else, então cada condição só vai ser executada uma caso a anterior seja falsa.

```
if(x >= 7){
         cout << "Aluno aprovado ! \n";
           }

else if(x <= 5){
         cout << "Aluno reprovado ! \n";
            }
else{
         cout << "Aluno em recuperação ! \n";
             }
```